# Bypassing MAX_PATH limitation for ITEMIDLIST?

Tags: winapi, shell, path, shell32

Is there any known way (whether documented or otherwise) to create an `ITEMIDLIST` structure from a path, such as with `ILCreateFromPath`, while bypassing the `MAX_PATH` limitation on the length?

Comment: Did you try to prefix `\\?\pszPath` with Unicode version `ILCreateFromPathW`? You could also try [`SHSimpleIDListFromPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762254%28VS.85%29.aspx) (it is *not* deprecated)

Comment: I am not having an issue with ILCreateFromPathW under Windows 7. Anyone else?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SHParseDisplayName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762236%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead. The documentation does not mention any limitation of the length of *pszName*.

Comment: It gives me `E_INVALIDARG`. Looks like poor documentation.

Comment: It is probably not possible since Windows shell does not support long pathes (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx for reference).